# Spring 4 support for Spring Security SAML

Tags: spring-4, spring-saml

I tried the [Spring Security SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) sample application with **Spring 4** and it doesn't work, but I have not investigated any further.
Is the main module (Spring Security SAML, v1.0.1) expected to work in a Spring 4 environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security SAML 1.0.1 final can be used with Spring Security 4  -  Spring Doc : [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#section-dependencies) Refer Section 2.1  New features, improvements and fixes in 1.0.1.FINAL

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same version of Spring-Saml (1.0.1.RELEASE) and it works for me. If you still have problems more information about your configuration is needed.

Comment: Please use the comment feature on the original question to start discussions. The answer format is not ideal to discuss back and forth.